# Rails audited search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, acts-as-audited

I'm trying to find every items that has been set to a specifique status last year. 
I'm using Rail 5 with audited so I created a specific Audit Model and I try to write a scope to return my condition :

```
Audit = Audited.audit_class

class Audit
  scope :followupRebus, -> { where(auditable_type: 'Followup')
    .where(action: 'update')
    .where("audited_changes LIKE '%step_id:[#{Step::REBUS}%'")
  }

end
```

the content of the audited text field in postgres looks like this when I take it and show it with a `.to_s`

```
{"step_id"=>[9, 4], "active"=>[false, true]}
```

How can I get all audit with `step_id = 9` ?

**EDIT**

Great thanks to DRSE, I finally found a working solution :

1. changing the default TEXT type of the Column with the migration sent by DRSE
2. Change the request like this :

   class Audit
     scope :followupRebus, -> { where(auditable_type: 'Followup')
       .where(action: 'update')
       .where("((audited_changes -> 'step_id')::json->>0)::int = :step_id", step_id: Step::REBUS)
     }

   end

Comment: Do you care if the previous version or the newer version has `step_id = 9`?  In your example `"step_id"=>[9, 4]` this shows that the previous version of your model had `step_id = 9` because the `9` is the first element in the array.

Comment: Yes, it should be a + but it's to vital for my needs

Comment: I have included all cases in my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [Postgres JSON functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) to query the JSON column audited_changes instead of the LIKE operator.

To find audits where the `step_id` was changed, you can use

```rb
.where("(audited_changes -> 'step_id')::jsonb ? :step_id", step_id: '9')
```

Note the use of the [named bind variable](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) `:step_id`, instead of using active record question mark (`?`) replacement because Postgres uses the question mark as a JSON query operator.

The clause above will find any audits where `step_id = 9`, whether that was the value set in the previous version or the updated version of your model.

To find audits where `step_id = 9` in the the previous version:

```rb
# Check if the first value (indexed by 0) in 'step_id' array is '9'
.where("(audited_changes -> 'step_id')::jsonb->0 ? :step_id", step_id: '9')
```

To find audits with `step_id = 9` set in the updated version:

```rb
# Check if the second value (indexed by 1) in 'step_id' array is 9
.where("(audited_changes -> 'step_id')::jsonb->1 ? :step_id", step_id: '9')
```

(Note: you should not directly string interpolate your conditions for your where clause because you are opening your app to a [SQL injection vulnerability](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection). Use [rails style conditions with sanitized inputs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions) instead.)

### EDIT

Since you have indicated that your audited_changes column type is TEXT and not a JSON type, you will need to either run a migration to change the column type or else cast the column in the query.

To cast the column to JSON at query execution time, use `audited_changes::json`, so the example would be like this:

```rb
.where("(audited_changes::json -> 'step_id')::json ? :step_id", step_id: '9')
```

To change the column to JSON, start with `rails g migration ChangeAuditedChangesColumnToJSONB`. Then in your migration file (`db/migrate/{timestamp}_change_audited_changes_column_to_jsonb.rb`) write:

```rb
class ChangeAuditedChangesColumnToJSONB < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def up
    change_column :audits, :audited_changes, :jsonb, using: 'audited_changes::JSONB'
  end

  def down
    change_column :audits, :audited_changes, :text
  end
end
```

Then run `rails db:migrate` and you should be good to go.

For a new project using Audited, you can [add a param to the install step](https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited#installation) to specify the use of JSON or JSONB type for the audited_changes column.

```rb
rails generate audited:install --audited-changes-column-type jsonb # or json
```

Comment: Thank you for your reactivity and the quality of your answer.

Comment: No problem. If it solves the problem for you, please mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks.

Comment: I tried your solution, but the audited_changes of the audited gem is typed in TEXT so I got the following error  
operator does not exist: text -> unknown

Note i'm on postgres 9.6
Do you know how to cast it ?

Comment: @Jaycreation please see my updated answer with instructions for how to change the column type from TEXT to JSONB.

Comment: thank you but it's looks that the syntax used by audited is not really json friendly , after transformation I got an error :
Token "-" is invalid.
Just like when I was trying to cast the text to jon

Comment: Can you add to your original post your version of Audited, the error you are receiving with backtrace, and the line that is causing the error, and any other details that may be relevant like a SQL error from Postgres if there is one.

Comment: I have added another way to cast the column to JSON in the query without changing the database schema.  Please try this as well if you would rather not/are unable to change your database.

Comment: I tried this one, the result is operator does not exist: json ? integer
AND (audited_changes::json -> 'step_id')::json->0 ? 9

Comment: finally, I manage to do something like that :
AND ((audited_changes -> 'step_id')::json->>0)::int = 5 ;

I'm not really happy about that solution but it works